# Form with target="_blank" returning PDF not working in home screen web-app

Tags: angular, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

In my Angular app I have a `form` with `target="_blank"` which, after submit, returns a PDF.

This works fine in every browser, but not if I do it from my homescreen icon of the web-app in Android/Chrome.

There is a new window opening but it stays blank, and the PDF does not show.

What needs to be done to be able to view the PDF?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial goal was to have the PDF displayed embedded in a new tab.
Of course this can not work from an iOS homescreen icon.

After some trying I found the best way to resolve my issue was to simply get rid of `target="_blank"`.

It looks all the browsers handle it fine and offer a download-dialog, and actually display the PDF when selecting "download".